# Can I play movies without X launched?

Tags: command-line, video, multimedia, console

I know that I dont need a GUI for browsing Internet (using Links) but what about doing other things like playing movies, music and pictures slide shows. Is it possible to do that in a text mode command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For playing movies have a look at MPlayer with video output devices `cvidix` oder `directfb`, see the [MPlayer documentation](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/video.html)
- For music cmus or ncmpc should work
- For pictures there's fbi

You need to bee a member of the `video` group to use graphics at the text console.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
aview image.jpeg
mplayer -vo aa:bold:dim:driver=slang: movie.mpeg
```

Both incantations use an [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) library. The `aview` program is in the [aview](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aview)  package. There's also `cacaview` from the [caca-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/caca-utils) package, and its associated driver for mplayer:

```
cacaview image.jpeg
mplayer -vo caca movie.mpeg
```

Of course, the picture quality is lousy. Aa has lots of parameters, but it's only with caca that I could almost make something out.

For real pictures, look for a player or viewer that advertises SVGAlib or FBdev support. This includes several mplayer drivers.

There's not much to gain by not starting X. If you're going to use graphics, you might as well start X.

Sound does not require X anyway.